# UITableview - swipe to delete sometimes causes a button in the cell to be tapped

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using the default swipe to delete. I also have a button in my cell. If I start the swipe to delete from that button, it registers a tap. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but here's a quick answer in case someone needs it again.

When the UITableViewCell swipe starts, an extra UITapGestureRecognizer that cancels the swipe is added to the cell.

All you have to do (assuming you have not added any other gesture recognizers to the cell yourself), is check if any recognizers exist for your cell at the moment your button IBAction is called. If there are, it means that the cell is being swiped and you should not handle the button press.

E.g.

```
@implementation MySubclassedTableViewCell

    - (IBAction)myButtonHandler:(id)sender {
            if (self.gestureRecognizers.count) {
                    return;
            }

            // Handle your button press here.
    }

@end
```